# ruamel.yaml dump: how to stop map scalar values from being moved to a new indented line?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Hard to describe succinctly, so I'll demonstrate.

```py
from sys import stdout
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yml = YAML()
doc = """
kind: ImageSetConfiguration
apiVersion: mirror.openshift.io/v1alpha2
storageConfig:
  local:
    path: ./operator-images
mirror:
  operators:
  - catalog: registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.14
    packages:
    - name: rhods-operator
      channels:
      - name: fast
        minVersion: 2.7.0
        maxVersion: 2.7.0
    - name: nfd
      channels:
      - name: stable
  additionalImages:
  - name: quay.io/integreatly/prometheus-blackbox-exporter@sha256:35b9d2c1002201723b7f7a9f54e9406b2ec4b5b0f73d114f47c70e15956103b5
  - name: quay.io/modh/codeserver@sha256:7b53d6c49b0e18d8907392c19b23ddcdcd4dbf730853ccdf153358ca81b2c523
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:00c53599f5085beedd0debb062652a1856b19921ccf59bd76134471d24c3fa7d
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:4275eefdab2d5e32a7be26f747d1cdb58e82fb0cd57dda939a9a24e084bd1f7e
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:6fadedc5a10f5a914bb7b27cd41bc644392e5757ceaf07d930db884112054265
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:88d80821ff8c5d53526794261d519125d0763b621d824f8c3222127dab7b6cc8
"""
y = yml.load(doc)
yml.dump(y, stdout)
```

Which prints:

```yaml
kind: ImageSetConfiguration
apiVersion: mirror.openshift.io/v1alpha2
storageConfig:
  local:
    path: ./operator-images
mirror:
  operators:
  - catalog: registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.14
    packages:
    - name: rhods-operator
      channels:
      - name: fast
        minVersion: 2.7.0
        maxVersion: 2.7.0
    - name: nfd
      channels:
      - name: stable
  additionalImages:
  - name: 
      quay.io/integreatly/prometheus-blackbox-exporter@sha256:35b9d2c1002201723b7f7a9f54e9406b2ec4b5b0f73d114f47c70e15956103b5
  - name: 
      quay.io/modh/codeserver@sha256:7b53d6c49b0e18d8907392c19b23ddcdcd4dbf730853ccdf153358ca81b2c523
  - name: 
      quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:00c53599f5085beedd0debb062652a1856b19921ccf59bd76134471d24c3fa7d
  - name: 
      quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:4275eefdab2d5e32a7be26f747d1cdb58e82fb0cd57dda939a9a24e084bd1f7e
  - name: 
      quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:6fadedc5a10f5a914bb7b27cd41bc644392e5757ceaf07d930db884112054265
  - name: 
      quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:88d80821ff8c5d53526794261d519125d0763b621d824f8c3222127dab7b6cc8
```

Why do the `name: xxx` dicts in the `mirror.additionalImages` list get split over two lines when dumping? Is it based on the length of the key's value or something? How can I stop this? (On a file with hundreds of those, it really gets ridiculous.) I've played with various settings of the `YAML()` instances, to no avail. (E.g., `indent()` and `compact()` and `default_flow_style`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default width for output in a YAML instance is 80 characters, that is what causing the values (which are too long),
to wrap to the next line.

If you set `yaml.width` to some larger value, this won't happen:

```py
from sys import stdout
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.width = 1024     # added line
doc = """
kind: ImageSetConfiguration
apiVersion: mirror.openshift.io/v1alpha2
storageConfig:
  local:
    path: ./operator-images
mirror:
  operators:
  - catalog: registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.14
    packages:
    - name: rhods-operator
      channels:
      - name: fast
        minVersion: 2.7.0
        maxVersion: 2.7.0
    - name: nfd
      channels:
      - name: stable
  additionalImages:
  - name: quay.io/integreatly/prometheus-blackbox-exporter@sha256:35b9d2c1002201723b7f7a9f54e9406b2ec4b5b0f73d114f47c70e15956103b5
  - name: quay.io/modh/codeserver@sha256:7b53d6c49b0e18d8907392c19b23ddcdcd4dbf730853ccdf153358ca81b2c523
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:00c53599f5085beedd0debb062652a1856b19921ccf59bd76134471d24c3fa7d
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:4275eefdab2d5e32a7be26f747d1cdb58e82fb0cd57dda939a9a24e084bd1f7e
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:6fadedc5a10f5a914bb7b27cd41bc644392e5757ceaf07d930db884112054265
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:88d80821ff8c5d53526794261d519125d0763b621d824f8c3222127dab7b6cc8
"""
y = yaml.load(doc)
yaml.dump(y, stdout)
```

which gives:

```
kind: ImageSetConfiguration
apiVersion: mirror.openshift.io/v1alpha2
storageConfig:
  local:
    path: ./operator-images
mirror:
  operators:
  - catalog: registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.14
    packages:
    - name: rhods-operator
      channels:
      - name: fast
        minVersion: 2.7.0
        maxVersion: 2.7.0
    - name: nfd
      channels:
      - name: stable
  additionalImages:
  - name: quay.io/integreatly/prometheus-blackbox-exporter@sha256:35b9d2c1002201723b7f7a9f54e9406b2ec4b5b0f73d114f47c70e15956103b5
  - name: quay.io/modh/codeserver@sha256:7b53d6c49b0e18d8907392c19b23ddcdcd4dbf730853ccdf153358ca81b2c523
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:00c53599f5085beedd0debb062652a1856b19921ccf59bd76134471d24c3fa7d
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:4275eefdab2d5e32a7be26f747d1cdb58e82fb0cd57dda939a9a24e084bd1f7e
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:6fadedc5a10f5a914bb7b27cd41bc644392e5757ceaf07d930db884112054265
  - name: quay.io/modh/cuda-notebooks@sha256:88d80821ff8c5d53526794261d519125d0763b621d824f8c3222127dab7b6cc8
```

Comment: Ohhhh my goodness @Anthon thank you! I can't believe I didn't know about that.

Comment: At some point I will keep track of the maximum line length of the input, and adjust `width` automatically on round-trip, it is on the todo list for an improved token scanner. Of course there will still be people running into problem with that, when they change values from shorter to longer scalars. Alternatively I could set width to MAX_INT and keep track of where all scalars are wrapped (like is done on Folded scalars). So much to do, so little time....